# Python 3: how to get nic from which will be sent packets to certain ip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, network-programming, python-requests

I have machine with multiple NICs that can be connected to one net, to different nets or every other possible way. Python script that uses requests module to send POST/GET requests to the server is ran on that machine.

So, the question is next: how can I know in python script from which interface requests will be sent?

Comment: Do you *really* need to know that, or is it just for personal curiosity? Because the operating systems routing will make sure that the correct packet goes out on the right interface.

Comment: Yes, I know that OS will choose the correct one, so I need to get NIC which would be used by OS for some other use in program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there are two different answers. The one is for the case where you want to specify the NIC to send the request and the other is for what you're asking: find the correct NIC.

For the second answer, I can only say that it depends. Are these NICs on the same network / subnet? Are they bonded?

If they are on a different network then you can know the host IP Address and use the computer's routing table to see which NIC the packet will go through. If they are bonded on the same network then the request will leave from the bond interface since it is (normally) the one with an IP Address. If they are on the same network and have a different IP on the same subnet then it depends. Can you provide some more information in that case?

Comment: To be more exact I need to know ip from which I will send requests. The problem is that I can't know network configuration, and it can be changed when program is running. 

Machine can have any possible number of NICs and every NIC will have it's own IP - it is definitely.